# How to initialize a Lock?

Tags: java, android

I am simply trying to read documentation for TimeUnit in android studio. Here is the link

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

However I am slightly confused on how to read and understand it correctly.

For example, the following code will timeout in 50 milliseconds if the lock is not available:

```
 Lock lock = ...;
 if (lock.tryLock(50L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) ...
```

How do I initialize this?

I have tried `Lock lock = new Lock();` ---but this makes me implement all of the methods. I am simply trying to use it how the documentation describes it.

Comment: "How to understand documentation" is not a suitable question for SO; I've edited it out and left only the technical question.

Comment: @JJJ - You are correct in that it is not really suitable.  However ... understanding the documentation seems to be the OP's fundamental problem.  And the answer is (probably) 1) he needs to improve his English language reading skills, 2) he needs to take more time / care in reading the javadocs, and 3) he needs to improve his Java language skills so that he *really* understands the difference between a class and an interface ... and why `new Lock` is an obvious non-solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the classes which implements the Lock interface such as `ReentrantLock`, `ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock`, `ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock`.

You can use [ReentrantLock](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) as:

```
 Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

And talking about the way to understand documentation, you should probably start with the basic stuffs such as `interface`

Comment: How did you even know to use ReentrantLock()? I don't even see it in the documentation...

Comment: @pewpew Check the docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: Glad I could help :)